# Create sender view url not always linking to envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I am creating sender view url by passing account id , envelope id and returl url. The generated url goes to console view and not to that particular envelope. It sometimes directly redirect to returnUrl without opening docusign. Earlier I tested sender view it was redirecting me to proper url. I do not why sender view url is working properly? Is there anything that I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only create the sender view - ie generate the URL token - for draft envelopes that are in `created` status. Also ensure the user attempting to generate the sender view has proper rights to the envelope.

Comment: Which view will be good to use if I am sender and I want to see that document in any status(sent,delivered, completed,voided)?

Comment: It doesn't work that way, if you want to open an embedded view of the envelope BEFORE it is sent then you need to generate the sender view.  If you want to sign the envelope in embedded fashion then you need to generate the recipient view.  See the API docs and dev center for more info.